# Sorting dataframe by absolute value of a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {0: [-1, -14], 1: [-3, 2], 2: [7, 10], 4: [-10, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I know how to sort an specific row:

```
df.sort_values(by=0, ascending=False, axis=1)
```

How is it possible to sort the dataframe by the absolute value of the first row?
In this case I will have something like:

```
sorted_data = {0: [-10, 15], 1: [7, 10], 2: [-3, 2], 4: [-1, -14]}
```

Answer (score 2):

sort series by slicing of row `0` and passing its index to indexing the original `df`

```
df_sorted = df[df.iloc[0].abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index]

Out[94]:
    4   2  1   0
0 -10   7 -3  -1
1  15  10  2 -14
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `argsort`

```
df = df.iloc[:,(-df.loc[0].abs()).argsort()]
```

Comment: I dont think this matches OP's expected output. probably ``df.iloc[:, df.loc[0].abs().argsort()[::-1]]``

Answer (score 1):

Pandas 1.1 gives a `key` argument :

```
df.sort_values(0, axis=1, key=np.abs, ascending=False)


      4  2   1    0
0   -10  7  -3   -1
1   15   10  2  -14
```